# How to use regex_findall in Ansible playbook properly?

Tags: regex, ansible

I have a problem using regex_findall in ansible playbook to pull ipv4 address from string. Here is ansible The offending line appears to be:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout | regex_findall('\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b') }}"
                                                         ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

with_items:
  - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"

exception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
exception: while parsing a quoted scalar
in "<unicode string>", line 29, column 14
found unknown escape character
in "<unicode string>", line 29, column 62
output
```

Where the problem can be ?

Comment: `\.` is not allowed in double quotes in YAML. There are only a number of escapes allowed. A backslash actually has to be escaped, though, to end up as a backslash. See http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092 and http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id872840

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's helpful if you give a reproducible example. Here's one:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    xyz: "hello"
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ xyz | regex_findall('\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b') }}"
  - debug: msg="done."
```

With `-vvv`, I get a more descriptive error message:

```
exception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
exception: while scanning a double-quoted scalar
  in "<unicode string>", line 7, column 12:
          msg: "{{ xyz | regex_findall('\b(?:[0 ...
               ^
found unknown escape character '.'
  in "<unicode string>", line 7, column 53:
     ...  regex_findall('\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b') }}"
```

So my first guess seems to have fixed it- double-backslash the backslashes.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    # xyz: "hello"
    xyz: "1.2.3.4"
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ xyz | regex_findall('\\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b') }}"
  - debug: msg="done."
```